# Error with Python Code on Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I wrote this simple script to do availability tests using the Shadowrun 5E rules based on data from a google form using Zapier. However, Zapier returns an error when I run this cool. Everything seems in order, what am I doing wrong?

```
import random 

itempoolgot = int(input_data.get('itempool'))
opposedpoolgot = int(input_data.get('opposedpool'))

itempoolloops = 0
itemhits = 0
opposedpoolloops = 0
opposedhits = 0
while (itempoolloops <= itempoolgot):
    diceresult = random.randint(1, 6)
    itempoolloops = itempoolloops + 1
    if diceresult >=5:
        itemhits = itemhits + 1

while (opposedpoolloops <= opposedpoolgot):
    diceresult = random.randint(1, 6)
    opposedpoolloops = opposedpoolloops + 1
    if diceresult >=5:
        opposedhits = opposedhits + 1
return {
    'opposedhits': opposedhits, 'itemhits' : itemhits
}
```

This is the error message "Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. :-( Error: 
Your code had an error!"

I've ran another code that just generates a random number and it works, it may be something wrong with the while loops.

Edit 2: By skipping the test step in Zapier, I found this error: Sent to Code "Run Python" failed: Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmpQdoNPW/usercode.py", line 16, in the_function diceresult = random.randint(1, 6) NameError: global name 'random' is not defined

Comment: "Zapier returns an error" -> we know about this problem _as much_ as you've written in your question. So, we can't read your mind and 'know' what the error is. Please include the exact error message in your post.

Comment: This is what I get "Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. :-( Error: 
Your code had an error!" I'm thinking Zapier may not allow while loops, as I ran a code without a while loop and it worked fine.

Comment: Zapier is notoriously bad at writing error messages.

Comment: Is it possible that your input data doesn't have both of those values? If you pass `None` to `int()` it'll raise an exception.

Comment: I found a typo in the code, but still am getting an error.

Comment: It's possible, let me do a test wpercy

Comment: Ha! I got more information out by skipping the test and running the Zapier function live.

Comment: "Sent to Code "Run Python" failed: Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmpQdoNPW/usercode.py", line 16, in the_function diceresult = random.randint(1, 6) NameError: global name 'random' is not defined"

Comment: I did import random as random and it worked, idk. I'm just going to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

I did "import random as random" at the beginning and it worked.